# Why no current passes through the middle row of capacitors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

[image]

I am supposed to find the equivalent capacitance of the given arrangement of capacitors (between A and B) I have figured out that I get the correct answer if I assume that the middle row of capacitor is shorted i.e no charge accumulates on them . But I am unable to find an appropriate and rigorous explanation for this. I have tried applying some symmetries but I doubt that they aren't clear and I am just trying to convince myself that I understand this question but I don't think so I do . Any help would be appreciated . Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine point A is at +V, and B is at -V (we can do this without loss of generality). By symmetry, every point midway between A and B must be at zero volts (because an identical network goes from that point to +V and to -V). But if every point on the midline is zero, there can be no voltage across any of the capacitors in the middle row.